# Scale columns in dataframe based on another column

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, scale, minmax

I have the dataframe shown below :

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.01 | 0.001 |
| 2 | 0.02 | 0.002 |
| 3 | 0.03 | 0.003 |

I want to scale column 2 and column 3 based on the min and max scaler of column 1, in order to obtain the following :

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |

These numbers are just imputed to understand the question easily.

All the solutions I have seen online basically uses a min max where they scale the columns between 0-1 but I want to scale it based on the min max of the first column.

Answer (score 1):

You can fit a min-max scaler on column 1 and apply it to other columns :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(df['column1'])
```

Apply it to column i :

```
df['column_i'] = scaler.transform(df['column_i'])
```

Comment: For me, the scaler.fit call gives an error `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

[@Adrien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558623/16343464) is very nice, but if you want to do it without external dependency:

```
MIN = df.min()
MAX = df.max()
(df-MIN)/(MAX-MIN)*(MAX['column1']-MIN['column1'])+MIN['column1']
```